# rotated K in return key

Tags: macos, keyboard

my apple laptop features a rotated K symbol in the return key.

I know it's supposed to be used with the fn key in combination with the return key. Accesible keyboard taught me so.

Could you please tell me its name so that I can search the Internet what is it about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

⌅ You mean this rotated K?

That's the  <kbd>Enter ⌅</kbd>  symbol.
Technically it's not the same as the  <kbd>Return ⏎</kbd>  but many apps consider them to be the same thing. 'Short' laptop keyboards don't have both keys, so this is a convenience.

For apps that **do** differentiate*, pressing  <kbd>Fn</kbd>   <kbd>Return ⏎</kbd>  will generate  <kbd>Enter ⌅</kbd> .

*The only one I can think of immediately is Photoshop in Text Entry mode. Return gives a new line, Enter exits text entry mode.